# VBA Use variable value across modules

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the name of a workbook which I set in module 1, across other private modules but I'm getting different errors depending on how I set it up. I added comments in the code that explain what happens in the different scenarios.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestSharedVars()

CopyCellsthenClose
OpenNewWksheet (AlphaExportBook)

' *** Like this
' OpenNewWksheet (AlphaExportBook) I get "Error Variable not defined"

' *** Like this
' OpenNewWksheet I get "Error Argument not optional"

CloseWkbook


End Sub

Private Sub CopyCellsthenClose()
Dim AlphaExportBook As Workbook
Dim theRows
Dim theColumns
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        theRows = .Rows.Count
        theColumns = .Columns.Count
        Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(theRows, theColumns)).Select
    End With
        Selection.Copy

    Set AlphaExportBook = ActiveWorkbook


End Sub


Private Sub OpenNewWksheet()

'******************************
'    Open the File Dialog
'******************************
Dim ReversionWBook As Workbook


    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        .Execute
  If (.SelectedItems.Count = 0) Then
        MsgBox "User Cancelled Operation"
'        GoTo EndofInstructions
    Else
    End If
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Activate
    Set ReversionWBook = ActiveWorkbook
End Sub

Private Sub CloseWkbook(AlphaExportBook As Workbook)

'**********************************
'  Close Alpha Export WorkBook
'**********************************
    AlphaExportBook.Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    AlphaExportBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shouldn't be getting an "Argument not optional" error when calling `OpenNewWksheet` because that subroutine is not expecting arguments.  You would get that error trying to call `CloseWkbook` without specifying a parameter, because that subroutine expects a `Workbook` object to be passed to it.

---

The easiest way to make the workbook available to all subroutines is to declare the variable with module-level scope, e.g.

```
Option Explicit
Dim AlphaExportBook As Workbook

Sub TestSharedVars()
    CopyCellsthenClose
    OpenNewWksheet
    CloseWkbook
End Sub

Private Sub CopyCellsthenClose()
    Dim theRows
    Dim theColumns
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        theRows = .Rows.Count
        theColumns = .Columns.Count
        'Note - the following line won't do what you expect unless
        '       UsedRange starts at cell A1
        Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(theRows, theColumns)).Select
    End With
    Selection.Copy

    Set AlphaExportBook = ActiveWorkbook
End Sub


Private Sub OpenNewWksheet()

'******************************
'    Open the File Dialog
'******************************
    Dim ReversionWBook As Workbook  ' Does this need to be module-level scope too?

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        .Execute
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "User Cancelled Operation"
        End If
    End With
    'ActiveWorkbook.Activate ' This is redundant - the ActiveWorkbook is already active
    Set ReversionWBook = ActiveWorkbook
End Sub

Private Sub CloseWkbook()

'**********************************
'  Close Alpha Export WorkBook
'**********************************
    'You don't need to activate the workbook before you close it
    'AlphaExportBook.Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    AlphaExportBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

---

Alternatively, you could pass the workbook object between subroutines as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestSharedVars()
    'Dimension object to have scope only within this subroutine, but we
    '  will pass a reference to this object to the other subroutines that
    '  need to reference it
    Dim AlphaExportBook As Workbook
    CopyCellsthenClose AlphaExportBook
    OpenNewWksheet
    CloseWkbook AlphaExportBook
End Sub

Private Sub CopyCellsthenClose(wb As Workbook)
    Dim theRows
    Dim theColumns
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        theRows = .Rows.Count
        theColumns = .Columns.Count
        'Note - the following line won't do what you expect unless
        '       UsedRange starts at cell A1
        Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(theRows, theColumns)).Select
    End With
    Selection.Copy

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
End Sub


Private Sub OpenNewWksheet()

'******************************
'    Open the File Dialog
'******************************
    Dim ReversionWBook As Workbook  ' Does this need to be module-level scope too?

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        .Execute
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "User Cancelled Operation"
        End If
    End With
    'ActiveWorkbook.Activate ' This is redundant - the ActiveWorkbook is already active
    Set ReversionWBook = ActiveWorkbook
End Sub

Private Sub CloseWkbook(wb As Workbook)

'**********************************
'  Close Alpha Export WorkBook
'**********************************
    'You don't need to activate the workbook before you close it
    'wb.Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```